# Passing text into "console" method on different form while running

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application with a form "Main" and a form "FileInfo."

The main form contains a method called "Console()" that takes a string input and an int mode. If the mode is 0 or 1 it appends the text to a textbox., if it mode is 1 or 2 it appends it to a text file in the logs directory.

On the second form, I have a bunch of tools that examine a file and give details about it. I'd like to pass some of these details back into the Console method on "Main" (from "FileInfo") and have it append to the textbox through the Console() method. Writing to the text file, of course, is easy but I cannot seem to be able to actively pass information back into the first form. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can create a method that takes those 2 values as out params or you can create utils class that's static and with your calls assign the values or pass back etc.. can you show your code this is actually not that diffucult

Answer (score -1):

The suggested way to do this with static. This means that the variable or class has the same value for all instances. Because of this you could make a small data storage class like this

```
public static class Data helper
{
    public static *type* var1;
    ....
}
```

Then in your second form take the data you want to pass back and set the values in the static class and then call an object of the static class in the main form and  you should be good to go.